# SharePoint 2013 Audit Log - Unrecognized Guid format Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing, reports

I am trying to run an audit report on a particular site within my site collection. I go to run a custom report, select the SAVE LOCATION, Start Date and restrict it to my site.

When I click OK to run the report, I immediately get the following error (by looking into the logs):

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.   
at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)   
at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result) 
at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.GetIdsFromSerializedId(String serializedId, Guid& listId, Guid& webId)  
at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Reporting.ApplicationPages.AuditCustomQuery.GetListFromControls(Guid& webId, Guid& listId)
at Microsoft... 186ccc9d-94fa-c0d2-61b8-572bc8ed8963
....Office.RecordsManagement.Reporting.ApplicationPages.AuditCustomQuery.GetQueryFromControls(Hashtable htResult)  
at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Reporting.ApplicationPages.AuditCustomQuery.get_Query()
at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Reporting.ApplicationPages.CustomizeReport.OKBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)  
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean in...186ccc9d-94fa-c0d2-61b8-572bc8ed8963
...cludeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 186ccc9d-94fa-c0d2-61b8-572bc8ed8963
```

Any idea what this might be?

This used to work 2 weeks ago and I've run this audit report multiple times before. I tried deactivating and reactivating the Reporting Feature, but that didn't work either.

I am able to retrieve the Audit reports using PowerShell, so the information is there. I'd like to get the UI to work though.

**EDIT:**

I tried a number of other reports such as "Auditing Settings" and "Security Settings." These reports all work. The custom one is the only one that seems to be failing.

Further logs show the error:

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/CustomizeReport.aspx, Error=Unrecognized Guid format.
```

When the "Auditing Settings" report is successful, this is the request:

```
Name=Request (GET:https://cs.valent.com:443/_layouts/15/CustomizeReport.aspx?ReportId=f43c916f-4450-4737-b889-8078c9826841&Category=Auditing)
```

So for some reason the custom report is missing the GUID when being run.

Answer (score 0):

The custom report lets you restrict itself to a site but it is actually looking for a list/library if you choose to restrict it. If you specify a site in the 'restrict report to' then it'll fail with the above error. You'll see this in the ULS:

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): 
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format. 

Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.GetIdsFromSerializedId(String serializedId, Guid& listId, Guid& webId)
at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Reporting.ApplicationPages.AuditCustomQuery.**GetListFromControls**(Guid& webId, Guid& listId)
```